# How would you search for property name and change (remove) it when found in Array of Arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, lodash

For example this is the Array of Arrays I have

```
arr: [ 
[
    {
      type: "some type",
      name: "some name"
    }, 
    {
      type: "some type",
      name: "some name"
    }
],
[
    {
      type: "some type",
      name: "some name"
    }, 
    {
      type: "some type",
      name: "some name",
      customAttr: "something custom"
    }
],
[
    {
      type: "some type",
      name: "some name"
    }, 
    {
      type: "some type",
      name: "some name"
    },
   customAttr: "something custom"
]];
```

I want to remove, or change whenever `customAttr` is found under this Array of Arrays. It can be found in Array layer, Objects layer, or even deeper. Also, I don't want to go from index 0, but after it.

I have tried this

```
arr.forEach(e => e).filter(s => s.customAttr)
```

but it only gets to one layer and I want to **mutate the array**

Is there a function, even in Lodash that can be used for this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't have a custom attribute like your last one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is eligible to you to flat array, then maybe it is for you:

```js
const arr = [
  [
      {
        type: "some type1",
        name: "some name"
      },
      {
        type: "some type2",
        name: "some name"
      }
  ],
  [
      {
        type: "some type3",
        name: "some name"
      },
      {
        type: "some type4",
        name: "some name",
        customAttr: "something custom"
      }
  ],
  [
      {
        type: "some type5",
        name: "some name"
      },
      {
        type: "some type6",
        name: "some name"
      },
      customAttr= "something custom1"
  ]
];



const flatArray = (arr) => {
  return arr.reduce(function (flat, toFlatten) {
    return flat.concat(Array.isArray(toFlatten) ? flatArray(toFlatten) : toFlatten);
  }, []);
  }

const flattened = flatArray(arr);
const result = flattened.filter(fi => fi.type && fi.name ).map(f=> {  
  return {
    type: f.type,
    name: f.name
  }
});
console.log(result);
```

**UPDATE:**

In case of avoiding of flattening array, you can do the following (be careful that it will work just for 2 dimensional array):

```js
const testArray = [
  [
  {
    type: "some type1",
    name: "some name"
  },
  {
    type: "some type2",
    name: "some name"
  }
  ],
  [
  {
    type: "some type3",
    name: "some name"
  },
  {
    type: "some type4",
    name: "some name",
    customAttr: "something custom"
  }
  ],
  [
  {
    type: "some type5",
    name: "some name"
  },
  {
    type: "some type6",
    name: "some name"
  },
  customAttr= "something custom1"
  ]
];

const beautifyArray = (srcArray) => {
  srcArray.forEach((el, i) => {
el = el.filter(fi=> fi.type && fi.name)
       .map(a => { return { type: a.type, name: a.name}});
testArray[i] = el;
  });
  console.log(testArray);
}

beautifyArray(testArray)
```

Comment: What if I wouldn't flat array?